# How do i center the_content in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, text, center

Is there a way/filter/codesnippet that makes the_content text always output as centered? Regardless if a person for example align the text left in the wysiwyg editor.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code maybe useful.

```
<!-- Add this div as parent div. -->
<div class="contentData"></div>
<style type="text/css">
.contentData {
     text-align:center;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to work with css...

```css
.CenterText{text-align:center!important;}
```

```html
<div class="CenterText">The Content echo</div>
```